# Parse error en Haskell

Tags: array, haskell

Soy nuevo en Haskell y también en programación. Estoy tratando de aprender Haskell con ejercicios ya realizados.

Justamente ahora me sale un error que dice lo siguiente.

> error: parse error on input "n", failed modules load: none

Del siguiente código

```
 listaMatriz :: Num a => [[a]] -> Matriz a
    listaMatriz xss = listArray ((1,1),(m,n)) (concat xss)
           where m = length xss
                 n = length (head xss)
```

¿Cúal creen que es el problema? No logro identificarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema de indentación. En Haskell, la indentación define dónde empieza y dónde termina un bloque de código. Todo lo que quieras definir dentro de `where` debe tener una indentación superior a este.

```
listaMatriz :: Num a => [[a]] -> Matriz a
listaMatriz xss = listArray ((1,1),(m,n)) (concat xss)
    where
        m = length xss
        n = length (head xss)
```

Por otra parte, aunque no es lo usual, puedes utilizar llaves `{}` y puntos y comas `;` para definir los bloques independientemente de la indentación:

```
listaMatriz :: Num a => [[a]] -> Matriz a
listaMatriz xss = listArray ((1,1),(m,n)) (concat xss)
    where {
        m = length xss;
        n = length (head xss)
    }
```

Puedes encontrar más información sobre estos errores comunes en la [wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Common_Misunderstandings).

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la segunda línea (debería empezar a la misma altura que la primera), el where está bien identado.

```
listaMatriz :: Num a => [[a]] -> Matriz a
listaMatriz xss = listArray ((1,1),(m,n)) (concat xss)
       where m = length xss
             n = length (head xss)
```

Comment: Deberías ser más específico, agregando el ejemplo y explicación